# How to add up a word based on month

Tags: excel

AI need to find how may times "Weddings" (column M) comes up in each July only and then add it to F8. Then in August and that that in F19.

In F8, I need to add up how many times "*" (column R) comes up with the reference "Wedding" only

in P8, I need to add up how many times "*" (Column R) comes up with reference to "Wedding" and Referred by "Peel" (column U)

[image: An external link to a screenshot of my Excel sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to find how may times "Weddings" (column M) comes up in each July only and then add it to F8

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",A13:A25,">="&DATE(2015,7,1),A13:A25,"<="&DATE(2015,7,31))
```

> Then in August and that that in F19

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",A13:A25,">="&DATE(2015,8,1),A13:A25,"<="&DATE(2015,8,31))
```

> I need to add up how many times "*" (column R) comes up with the reference "Wedding" only

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",R13:R25,"*")
```

But, I guess you want count of `"*"` with `Wedding` in `July` and `August`.
For July:

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",R13:R25,"*",A13:A25,">="&DATE(2015,7,1),A13:A25,"<="&DATE(2015,7,31))
```

For August:

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",R13:R25,"*",A13:A25,">="&DATE(2015,8,1),A13:A25,"<="&DATE(2015,8,31))
```

> I need to add up how many times "*" (Column R) comes up with reference to "Wedding" and Referred by "Peel" (column U)

```
=COUNTIFS(R13:R25,"*",M13:M25,"Wedding",U13:U25,"Peel")
```

Again, I guess you want count of `"*"` with `Wedding` referred by `Peel` in `July` and `August`.

For July:

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",R13:R25,"*",U13:U25,"Peel",A13:A25,">="&DATE(2015,7,1),A13:A25,"<="&DATE(2015,7,31))
```

For August:

```
=COUNTIFS(M13:M25,"Wedding",R13:R25,"*",U13:U25,"Peel",A13:A25,">="&DATE(2015,8,1),A13:A25,"<="&DATE(2015,8,31))
```

**Note:** Change ranges as required.

Comment: That is great Mrig, some of these worked, and then when I added more months, and I changed some of the ranges, it stopped working on the new fields. Can I maybe send you what I am trying to do, and the formulas I already have? if not are you able to contact me? Thanks

Comment: @Navs - You can share your file, I'll go through it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, how do i get to @Navs, and then how do I up load a file?

Comment: @Navs - First question: Are you not Navs?

Comment: @Navs - You can upload your file on any of the online file sharing website and then share link with me.

Comment: Hi Mrig, I have re-done the spreadsheet. So I can show you exact figures, how do I share a link with you only. Thanks Navs

Comment: @Navs - Do you have Skype acc.?

Comment: @Navs - Mine is `mrigendrasingh9`. You can send your file to this acc.